# Best way to keep the list of servers, OSs, Databases and so on

Tags: configuration-management

I have a Microsoft Visio file in which I list the list of sever my organization has, but not only that, also wich OS they have, Databases, and so on. The problem with the Visio file is that is something static and very graphic oriented. I would like to have a more structured approach while having at the same time a graphical representation of this information.
Do you have a better approach?
Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want a list, anything can help you (notepad, excel, visio, etc.) Finally you won't change servers, dbs or OS frequently. You can use Microsoft Active Directory Topology Diagrammer for generate diagrams from your AD, for example (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13380). But I think must usefull for you will be something for monitoring your assets (PRTG, Nagios, etc.) and you can get a dashboard with a graphical representation and also the status of each device/service

Comment: Related tags [tag:asset-management] [tag:cmdb] Related question  https://serverfault.com/questions/633851/how-do-people-manage-their-inventory-of-servers Note that a database generally doesn't reside on one OS, but multiple. One server generally doesn't contain one OS, but multiple. One OS generally doesn't have one IP, but multiple. One IP is not generally hosted on one OS, but on multiple (many-to-many relation).

Comment: ConnectedText with the Navigator Tool ( a link visualizer ) could be an interesting way to do this, if you constructed your articles to take advantage of it.  http://www.connectedtext.com/screenshots.php